# Add figure format reference to an image added on a minipage

Tags: floats, minipage

I have the following minipage:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[ht]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth] {fig/grafo1.eps}
        \label{fig:g1_5}
        \captionof{figure}{Grafo de ejemplo(¿?).}
    \end{minipage}
    \quad
    \begin{minipage}[ht]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Iteración\\ Vértice\end{tabular} & 1                         & 2                          & 3                         & 4                         \\ \hline
            1                                                           & -1                        & -1                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}1  & -                         \\ \hline
            2                                                           & -3                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}-1 & -                         & -                         \\ \hline
            3                                                           & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}0 & -                          & -                         & -                         \\ \hline
            \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}4                                   & -                         & -                          & -                         & -                         \\ \hline
            5                                                           & -2                        & -2                         & 0                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}2 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{Ejemplo de una construcción voraz.}
        \label{tab:cv}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
```

And after that I tried to refenrence the figure:

```
Now I reference \ref{fig:g1_5}
```

The minipage is seen like:

[image]

As you can see, figure caption is ok, but reference it is not:

> Now I reference 4.3.2

(It is the number of the section)

How I can use the figure reference in the minipage?

It may be:

> Now I reference Figure 4.4

Comment: A figure reference must be in a figure-like float.  Think of minipages as sub-sections for the purpose of labels.

Comment: Is there any way to deceive latex, and make it think it is a reference of a figure? In the same was as I used captionof{figure}

Comment: @Sergio Cavero: You should provide a compilable MWE. What class and packages are you using?

Comment: Sorry Marian, but I was writing a book and I was using to many packages... @MarianG.

Comment: In the future, your MWE should include only packages required to produce the error.  Make it easy for helpers to reproduce your error.  So for this MWE you would just need `graphicx` and `xcolor` with the table option (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\label` *always*  after `\caption`!

```
   \captionof{figure}{Grafo de ejemplo(¿?).}
   \label{fig:g1_5}
```

Comment: What an inattention! Many thanks.